# Data member changing while transferring the data back from the constructor to the calling method

Tags: c++, constructor

When I deserialize an object my Square constructor changes the value of my `ch` to something unknown. I can't understand why.

```
bool Palette::addShape(int shape, fstream &input)
{
    int x, y, len;
    double shiftX, shiftY;
    char ch;

    input >> x >> y >> len >> ch;
    Shape *toAdd;
    std::list<Shape *>::iterator itr;

    switch (shape)
    {
    case RectangleID:
        toAdd = new Rectangle(x, y, len, ch);
        palette.emplace_back(toAdd);
        break;
    case SquareID:
        toAdd = new Square(x, y, len, ch);
        palette.emplace_back(toAdd);
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is the constructor:

```
Square(int x, int y, int length, char chIn) : Shape(x, y, length, ch)
{
    shapeId = SquareID;
}
```

When I debug the constructor I see that it gets the right values, but when I check the value of `toAdd` after the constructor returns I see the junk in `ch`. I know it's a c'tor problem since it does not happen when I add a new Rectangle.

Comment: Did you mean for your parameter to be chIn.  If your class has a member named ch, you are using that junk value to initialize it.

Comment: Those are the most untraceable bugs. I get stuck in a convention that everything is alright and I would have done the same mistake again even if I was rewriting the c'tor. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be untraceable. With compiler warnings turned on (`-Wall -Wextra`), which they should be, any mainstream compiler [will warn you about an uninitialised member or unused parameter](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb2fb2ff80fe8bc4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Square(int x, int y, int length, char chIn) : Shape(x, y, length, ch)
> //                                    ^^^^                        ^^
> ```

The parameter is called `chIn`, but you initialised the member `ch` with itself instead.

This results in its unspecified, pre-initialisation value.

I think you meant to write:

```
 Square(int x, int y, int length, char chIn) : Shape(x, y, length, chIn)
 //                                                                ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Square(int x, int y, int length, char chIn) : Shape(x, y, length, ch)
                                                                  ^^
```

What is `ch` here? Looks like you meant `chIn`.